# NSDateFormatter not outputting what I expect

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have the following code that is supposed to format a time string ("0800") so I can then format it again into HH:MM format for display.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
if([timeString intValue] < 1000)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"Hmm";
else
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HHmm";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
```

If the time string length is less than 4 characters, then the format string is altered accordingly.

The problem is that if the time string is 0800, the dateFormatter returns **nil** from the conversion of *timeString*.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HHmm` regardless of the integer value of the time string. `0800` has the format `HHmm`, not `Hmm`. If the string were `800` then using `Hmm` would make sense.